# plauthorname undefined when using publist

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-publist

I want to build a publication list for myself using `biblatex-publist`. I follow the instruction in the doc version 1.11 but I get the error message

> Undefined control sequence. l.4 \plauthorname
>                    {Frank} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed.

My trivial small example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}

\plauthorname{Frank}
\addbibresource{AFcleanarticles.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{Andrew U. Frank's publications}
\date{\today}
\maketitle


\section{Articles}
\newrefsection[AFcleanarticles]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none] 

\end{document}
```

the log file - following the suggestion - says:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex bibstyle data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'publist.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
```

and indeed I have no biblatex-dm.cfg and have 
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-publist/publist.cbx`
and the correspoinding `dbx`.

More from the log:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'publist'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'publist.bbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-publist/publist.bbx
File: publist.bbx 2016/08/06 v.1.3 biblatex bibliography style (JSP)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.bbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authoryear.bbx
File: authoryear.bbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count271
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count272
))
\extralabelnumberwidth=\skip57
)
```

The installation is with debian packages on a linux-debian(stretch) system.

what am I doing wrong? Help appreciated!

Comment: The MWE compiles without error for me. Can you double check in the `.log` that LaTeX really loads the version of `biblatex-publist` you think it loads.

Comment: Following the suggestion of #moeve, I have pasted the relevant (?) part of the log file and checked where the requested files are. They seem not to be at the right place. Why? How to fix?

Comment: `publist.bbx 2016/08/06 v.1.3 biblatex bibliography style` is definitely not version 1.11. Not sure if the macro was renamed in the meantime or just did not exist back in 2016. You may have better luck following the instructions for your outdated version 1.3. You can get the documentation of your installed version with `texdoc biblatex-publist`.

Comment: Aha! According to https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/tree/0dae8f681c61524aa6c492d926b1b9062af30d26 `\plauthorname` was called `\omitname` in version 1.3. Try that or consider updating your TeX distribution.

Comment: I added more from the log file - probably only the first couple of lines are relevent. They seem to indicate that the version loaded is 1.3 from 2016. I cannot find a documentation of this version. How can I load the current version from CTAN? is it enough to download and put into the same place where pbulist.bbx is now?

Comment: I tried /omitname but then other errors occur. I will try to update my installation. Thanks a lot for identifying the cause!

Comment: What other errors do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.log` snippets show that your TeX distribution has version 1.3 of `biblatex-publist`, that version dates back to August 2016.

According to https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/tree/0dae8f681c61524aa6c492d926b1b9062af30d26 the macro that is now called `\plauthorname` was called `\omitname` back then. So you may have more luck when you replace `\plauthorname` with `\omitname` in the above example.

Usually you can access the documentation of the package version installed on your machine by typing `texdoc <package>` in the command line. In your case `texdoc biblatex-publist` should bring up the documentation of version 1.3. It is generally safer to consult the documentation of the version you have installed rather than the documentation of the newest version on CTAN (though I will admit that I am so used to googling everything that reading the documentation on CTAN happens more naturally than going to a command line and calling `texdoc`, but I'm trying to get better).

If you want to update your TeX system, have a look at [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864). If you are running a TeX live that was installed via the package repositories of your Linux distribution, chances are you can not update. In that case you have to install a vanilla TeX live from TUG if you want to live on the bleeding edge of development (see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)). It is usually a *very, very* bad idea to manually update packages from CTAN. Especially with `biblatex` and Biber you can easily run into incompatibilities.

Comment: You're a MSWindows user, I see.  ;)   Here, "Alt+F2" gives me an execute command prompt in which `texdoc` fits perfectly.

Comment: @gusbrs My cover is blown! I guess I could use Win+R and type in `texdoc --view <package>` (MikTeX otherwise sends me to a HTML selection screen, which I hate) and would be about as quick. But old habits ...

Comment: hahaha Yes it is! Btw, the "Win" key is called "Super" elsewhere. In a Xfce distro I'm playing with, it is even nicer. The menu lets you put a command directly in the search, so "Super + texdoc biblatex + RET" takes you straight to the sweet spot.